# Select all child controls at once?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4-sydney

In the Delphi IDE, is it possible to select e.g. all controls placed on a `TPanel`?
I want to shift all these down so that I can add a new control at the top of the panel.
Currently I Shift-Click all these controls but that's a PITA.

Right-click and 'Select All' selects all controls on the form.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Structure view (View / Tool Windows / Structure or Ctrl-Alt-F11), you can then click the top one and shift-click the bottom one to select them all:

[image]

Note: Your focus is not on the form after the selection, press F12 twice to get there.

---

Alternatively, use `Ctrl` - `Left Mouse Button` - click on the panel and drag to select visually

Comment: Or `Ctrl` - `Left Mouse Button` - click on the panel and drag to select visually

Comment: Holding `Ctrl` while dragging a selection rectangle works at least since D7 from 20 years ago and it rock solidly retains to the child area it has started in. Back then your solution was called "_Object TreeView_" and multi-selecting items in there works as in any treeview.

Comment: I did not know that either, @TomBrunberg. Make it a second answer ;-)

Comment: I think it is better to include the alternative in your answer.